# Heroku + Node.js. Error "Cannot find module 'request"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I just started learning Node.js and pushed it to Heroku. However, the problem keeps popping up even I tried to delete and install again. Can anyone show me what is wrong in my program because I have been looking for the answers but could not find it.

My package

```
{
  "name": "mailchimp-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "test_mail.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node test_mail.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

```
2020-08-15T05:17:40.937553+00:00 app[api]: Set NODE_MODULES_CACHE config vars by user kevkwok0401@gmail.com
2020-08-15T05:17:40.937553+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user kevkwok0401@gmail.com
2020-08-15T05:17:41.145484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-15T05:17:43.045731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-08-15T05:17:45.501773+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-15T05:17:45.501798+00:00 app[web.1]: > mailchimp-api@1.0.0 start /app
2020-08-15T05:17:45.501799+00:00 app[web.1]: > node test_mail.js
2020-08-15T05:17:45.501799+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690259+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690260+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690261+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690261+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690262+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'request'
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690262+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690263+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/test_mail.js
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690263+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690264+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690268+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690268+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/test_mail.js:3:17)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690270+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690270+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690271+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690271+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690271+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/test_mail.js' ]
2020-08-15T05:17:45.690272+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-08-15T05:17:45.700493+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-15T05:17:45.700865+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-08-15T05:17:45.705245+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mailchimp-api@1.0.0 start: `node test_mail.js`
2020-08-15T05:17:45.705417+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-08-15T05:17:45.705606+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-08-15T05:17:45.705730+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mailchimp-api@1.0.0 start script.
2020-08-15T05:17:45.705885+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-15T05:17:45.715163+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-15T05:17:45.715315+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-15T05:17:45.715389+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-08-15T05_17_45_707Z-debug.log
2020-08-15T05:17:45.788233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-15T05:17:45.831930+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-15T05:17:51.690184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=enigmatic-stream-86051.herokuapp.com request_id=0cd0dcc0-e884-4704-aabf-dc8ad2089829 fwd="98.252.127.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

EDIT: Need to install npm install request.

Comment: You are using request module inside you node.js code and have not added that to your dependencies in your package.json file
When the server is booted on Heroku it install the package dependencies in which the request module is missing .

Add request module dependency in your package.json and redeploy your code to Heroku it should work.

Comment: Ok got it thank you